# problem in posting data from client side to server side in OnetoOneMapping

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC when I submit data from my form then the exception occurs as given below.

The situation is like I have Entity class and I have taken another Entity in it as part of relationship. when I send data to display it is working properly but when I post data after editing exception occurs. I have tried initbinding as well but doesn't work.

```
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'user' of bean class [org.mkcl.iforum.adnan.domain.UsersCredentials]: Value of nested property 'user' is null
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:453)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:428)
 at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:645)
 at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:78)
 at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:532)
 at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:434)
 at org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder.doBind(WebDataBinder.java:147)
 at org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestDataBinder.bind(ServletRequestDataBinder.java:108)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ArgumentsResolver.resolveArguments(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:598)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:242)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:874)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:808)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
 at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:359)
 at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
 at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:268)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:87)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:61)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:116)
 at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
 at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:174)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at test.HttpsCookieFilter.doFilter(HttpsCookieFilter.java:37)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't give a complete answer with the current level of details but you might be interested by [SPR-6032](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6032), [SPR-1671](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-1671) and [SPR-1860](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-1860). Could the new `autoGrowNestedPaths` added to the `DataBinder` help in your case?

Comment: giving more clarity to the question. I have class UserCredentials as below